# biblatex: Undefined control sequence. \lbx@lfromlang ->\iffieldundef

Tags: biblatex, errors

I'm a bit stuck here. While trying to change my document from plain bibtex to biblatex (for some various reason of cite handling) I'm stuck at this error message:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@lfromlang ->\iffieldundef 
                           {origlanguage} {} {\bibstring {from\thefield ...
l.131 \begin{document}
```

As far as I understand that, this is part of the biblatex *.lbx files. For that I tried some other languages with the babel packages and voilà it is working.

Next step. Make a minimal example with the same bibfile, trying to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{00a_thesis.bib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
 Text with cite \cite{novikova:2011}\\

 \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is working perfectly.

Can any one help me figuring out what is causing this strange behavior? 
To rule out a bug in biblatex I also tried without any luck the 2.8 development branch.

EDIT:
The Bibtex entry for novikova:2011

```
@report{novikova:2011,
     author = "Novikova, Aleksandra and Amecke, Hermann and Neuhoff, Karsten and Stelmakh, Kateryna and Kiss, Bernadett and Rohde, Clemans and Dunkelberg, Elisa and Matschoss, Kaisa and Darby, Sarah",
     title = "Information tools for energy demand reduction in existing residential buildings",
     institution = " Climate Policy Initiative (CPI)",
     year = 2011,
     month = "27~" # jun,
     type = "Study",
     url = "http://enef-haus.de"
}
```

Comment: Could we have the BibTeX entry for `novikova:2011`?

Comment: Try to make an example that shows the error.

Comment: I tried your example with the given entry and it works fine for me. can you provide an example producing the error?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue related to an outdated template of a university.


Comment: You shouldn't use quotes around the entries. If needed, brace them in a group `{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for my problem:
I was using a template provided by my university with its own class file. In that there were the command `\RequirePackage{ngerman}`.
Without that my file compiles fine with `biblatex`.

As far as I understand it the `\RequirePacke{ngerman}` is only useful if I want to use the shorthands of that package before `\begin{document}`.
In conclusion: If I don't use any of that in my commands I should be fine with just `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: The `ngerman` package is _never_ necessary. If you want/need `babel` shorthands active in the preamble: `babel` provides the proper options for this.

Comment: The `ngerman` package is largely obsolete; its last revision dates 1998-07-08; the present version of `babel` is surely superior, so your intervention is good. Please, tell the maintainers of the class to remove the obsolete package.